# How to check If particular Id already in Firebase collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Here , I want to check In All Documents that Uid  is already exist or not if not

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to query for this specific document and check if it exists as shown in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document). You don’t specify which language you are using so I cannot copy/paste the appropriate code but the different examples show exactly how to do, in particular by using the `exists` property/method of the `DocumentSnapshot`.

Comment: Thanks Bro, i tried this   const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
    query(collection(db, "Users"), where("UId", "==", user.uid))
  );
  return !querySnapshot.empty;

Comment: Ok, I understand: in your question you mentionned "If particular Id already in Firebase collection" therefore I understand that you were speaking about the Document ID, not the field `Uid`. Glad that you could find the solution.